# Kubernetes: creating permanent folders in pod

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pod, kubernetes-pvc

I have a pod in which I'm running a image.
The pod is not mine but belongs to the company I work for.
Each time I mount a new image in the pod it has access to some predefined "Permanent" folders.

When I use the edit deployment command I see this:

```
 volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /Data/logs
          name: ba-server-api-dh-pvc
          subPath: logs
        - mountPath: /Data/ErrorAndAbortedBlobs
          name: ba-server-api-dh-pvc
          subPath: ErrorAndAbortedBlobs
        - mountPath: /Data/SuccessfullyTransferredBlobs
          name: ba-server-api-dh-pvc
          subPath: SuccessfullyTransferredBlobs
        - mountPath: /Data/BlobsToBeTransferred
          name: ba-server-api-dh-pvc
          subPath: BlobsToBeTransferred
```

Now I want to manually add another such mountPath so I get another folder in the pod. But when I add it to the deployment config (the one above) and try saving it I get the following error.

```
"error: deployments.extensions "ba-server-api-dh-deployment" is invalid"
```

What can I do to add another permanent folder to the POD?

kind regards

Comment: What and how exactly are you doing it? Also please add full deployment yaml. It seems like it's missing a volume you tried to add or just syntax error

Comment: HI ! Sorry for the late reply! 
Any folder added through code present in the Img will be bound to that Img and its life cycle connected to the life cycle of that Img. Any permanent volume had to be added through the Kubernetes configurations in the PV config of the POD you are working with. 

As a coder i did not have access to these so I had to contact the Kubernetes cluster Admin who added them for me in the PV config and now it works fine. @Wytrzymały Wiktor

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you haven't specified the volume.

Something looks like this.

```
...
        volumeMounts:
          - mountPath: /Data/BlobsToBeTransferred
            name: ba-server-api-dh-pvc
            subPath: BlobsToBeTransferred
...
   volume:
     - name: ba-server-api-dh-pvc
       persistentVolumeClaim:
         claimName: ba-server-api-dh-pvc
```

Note that you already have a PersistentVolumeClaim named ba-server-api-dh-pvc, otherwise you will have to create.

Comment: Yeah sorry i have that part too just forgot to add it to my post.

Comment: Do you have PersistentVolumeClaim named ba-server-api-dh-pvc yet?

Comment: I did have that too i just could not edit it and  ad the volume i wanted to it since  i was not the cluster admin. It has now been done for me. Thank you for your help!